# How to install windows 7/8 inside Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,and I have a laptop with good configuration. I would like to install windows 8/7 **inside** my Ubuntu OS. Is it possible? If yes, what is the process? Can I install it from DVD?

Comment: Do you want to install Windows in a virtual machine or do you want to create a dual-boot installation?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible...with VMware:

[Link to Wiki for VMware](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/VMware_Workstation)

You should get vm-ware in the Ubuntu software-center and some other programs as well, that can make you a virtual mashine. And you can link a lot of your hardware to it, also the DVD-Drive to install from CD/DVD.

The software that you need for a GUI based virtual mashine under Ubuntu is called "virtualbox"...just looked it up in the ubuntu software center to make sure

;3)

Comment: VMware is not the only solution for virtualisation. But it's not clear to me if OP is asking for a virtualisation solution or that he's asking for a way to install it native like you can install Ubuntu inside Windows using Wubi (without virtualisation).

Comment: Well, it seamed like he wanted to know if Ubuntu has a virtual mashine solution and that I answeared...it was clear to me...nothing bad formulated.

Comment: If that's what he's asking I guess VMware is not really the "general" Ubuntu solution, because it's a commercial solution. Ubuntu's default virtualisation is KVM (see also "Virtual Machine Manager" in the Software Centre), but I prefer VirtualBox for GUI guest installations. I would recommend VMware only if there's a really good reason.

Comment: Well...I'm a Soft- and Hardware Tech that was trained on Windows first, so VMWare is the most common tool there for that...I extra searched out the link to the correct ubuntu software that came up in Google first and confirmed it in Ubuntu, if it's there and how it's called there.

Virtual Box...that's the correct answer.

Also VMWare is still the most known software around...it may coasts extra to unlock all it's features, but it is the software for this job, with most expirience...as I needed time to search out a free equivalent under Linux, I added that later.
;3)